# String interpolation with query params

Tags: angular

In Angular, can string interpolation be used with `queryParams`?

```html
<button routerLink="/user/{{ userId }}" [queryParams]="[{ type: '{{type}}' }]">
```

I am getting an error that expression is expected where I am using string interpolation.

Thanks..

Comment: Is the code you have provided above throwing an error? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1u3x91?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing interpolation `{{ }}` with data-binding `[]`. Use only either of it not together.

Try the following (data-binding)

```html
<!-- 
                                          `type` from *.ts -----
           `userId` from *.ts -----     property name -----    |   
                                  |                       |    |
                                  ▼                       ▼    ▼ 
-->
<button [routerLink]="['/user/'+userId]" [queryParams]="{type:type}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlink-ssf-mowv82?file=app%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html) and see how different queryParams are treated by angular. In general, you want to give an object with key-value pairs of the param and value, wrapping `[queryParams]` in the square brackets (linke in the "testing" link from the example)

[image]